# Python Error when working with numpy arrays (Tiff images) and performing background subtraction

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, tiff

I'm fairly new to creating functions in python and I wanted to make a function that can work on multiple Tiff images to perform background subtraction and output them to a new folder. I am stuck at the operation where I have 2 lists, one containing the files paths of the original images and one containing the minimum background arrays of the same images. I am now trying to subtract the minimum list from the original images, but I get this error:
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U100'), dtype('uint8')) -> None

I'm not sure of how to access objects within a list that contains tiff files for the subtratcion.

Please see the code and error attached below, any help is much appreciated.

```py
def open_images(file_list):
    for file in file_list:
        if os.path.exists(file):
            image = Image.open(file)
        else:
            print(f"File {file} does not exist.")

#Subtracting the min_list from the original list:
def subtract_minimum(original_list, minimum_list):
    open_images(original_list)
    for i in original_list:
        print(np.shape(i))
        for j in minimum_list:
            print(np.shape(j))
            og_sub_min = i - j
            sub_min_array = np.array(og_sub_min)
    return (sub_min_array)

green_sub_list = list(subtract_minimum(green_list, green_min_list))
print(green_sub_list)
```

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U100'), dtype('uint8')) -> None

Comment: If one list contains the paths to TIFF files, then you need to read in those TIFF files before you subtract. You cannot subtract a background array from a file path.

Comment: If that doesn’t solve your user, please read [mre], then [edit] the code in your post accordingly.

Comment: Hello Chris, I tried to read the TIFF files and open them within the function, however, it seems that the error is still unresolved. Is there another way to do this, to access the object itself as an array?

Comment: There's also the problem that `open_images` just reads images into the variable `image` and then does nothing with it.  They get thrown away.  I'm not sure what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Update, I fixed this by adding a return line instead of the else line, my object was converted to a NoneType due to the missing return.

Comment: Hello Frank, I added that function thinking it would allow the paths to be read and opened as tiff files, and then converted to numpy arrays so i could perform the subtraction with them. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I'm fairly new to programming, thank you for pointing that out and your help is appreciated!